# Will having many timers affect my game performance?

Tags: java, performance, timer

I'm making a game for android, and earlier today I was trying to add some cool stuff to my game. The problem is this thing needs like 5 timers. I build my timers like this:

```
timer += deltaTime;
if(timer >= 2.0f){
    doStuff;
    timer -= 2.0f;
} // this timers gets stuff done every 2 secs
```

Will having to many timers like this, getting checked every frame, screw up my games performance? The effect I wanted to add was a crosshair every 2 sec, then remove it after 2 sec and do a timed animation. So an array of crosshairs dependent on a bunch of timers to be exact. This caused my game to shut down when used, so thats why Im wondering if using that many timers causes my game to flip out.

Comment: i don't get if you are experiencing actual problems or you are pretending having one.

Comment: what? Its a simple question, "will it screw up my games performance having to many timers like this?" cus I plan to have more, and I want to find out if I can do it this way or if I need a new way, that is more performance-friendly.

Comment: how much is "more" ? That's the problem with your question, it's not clear and can't be answered because you do not have set any boundaries.

Comment: " timer -= 2.0f;" Makes little sense even though it looks logical. Why not timer = 0; ?

Comment: Indeed, @Sidar makes a good point. `timer = 0` is clearer: it communicates clearly you're _resetting_ the timer, not adjusting it. If you then ever adjust the timer to run every 4 seconds, you also won't ever have to worry about forgetting to change the `-= 2.0f` (which would turn it into a 2 second timer after the first step).

Comment: iQue! Don't change your timer behavior. timer -= 2.0f is better than timer = 0 because by the time the timer reaches 2.0f, it will be slightly over because of the way delta time works. Subtracting 2.0f instead of setting to 0 compensates for this. If you switch it to timer = 0, the timer will run slower and less accurately.

Comment: In that case it should be a variable.

Comment: Your reasoning is faulty. It will be slightly over, but then when you set it back by 2 seconds, it might be slightly under the next time. Overall we're talking a few microseconds here. The compensation isn't worth worrying about. What is worth worrying about is making your code clear, and not introducing bugs because you changed one value but forgot to change the other.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs This method of tracking time makes sure that time is never lost (always compensating).  A few stray microseconds per frame can add up really, really fast.  My point is, sometimes this logic can be useful.  Other times, it's not needed.  Who knows what the case is here.

Comment: Or just use a variable instead of magic numbers.

Comment: Resetting the timer with timer = 0; does not make the timer trigger every 2 second, so that would be wrong. Instead it will make the next one trigger after at least 2 seconds from the previous one even if the previous one was late.

Comment: > " timer -= 2.0f;" Makes little sense even though it looks logical. Why not timer = 0; ? <

Because "timer -= 2.0f;" will trigger exactly every 2 seconds where as "timer = 0;" will not unless all the deltaTimes add up to 2 exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the short timer code you posted, any number of those would be fine, it's what doStuff you do with each one.

One problem I can foresee is that if you have timers of different frequencies some of them will sometimes "beat" and trigger their doStuff code all at the same time.  For example, if you have a timer for 2.0 and one for 3.0, then every 6.0th tick both actions will get called simultaneously and maybe cause your game to burp when that happens.

Pick timer frequencies that won't all gang up like that, problem solved before it happens.

The question of "too many timers like that" can only be answered by asking "what do those timers DO" and then profiling to find out how much work you can afford and keep running smoothly.

Comment: thank you! I never thought if frequencies. I'm pretty sure this problem isnt frequencies tho as the second timer wont start until the first timer finishes. `(if timer1 >= 2.0f){add object to array with built in timer thats dissapears after that timer reaches 2.0f();}`  But this will help me in the future for sure.

Answer (score 1):

"Will X affect my game's performance" should always be answered by "profile it and find out".  Anything else is just guessing.

Comment: I understand that know. But since I have no experience with building a large game I thought someone that had would be able to answer if using to many timers is a poor way to execute code. Didnt know it would be such a big deal to people that I didnt give the EXACT amount of timers I planned on using. And wanted to avoid having to re-do half of my games functions just because I used poor code. there is a difference, imo, in an experienced guess and an unexperienced one.

Comment: A number of data manipulations, sorts in particular, have specific breaking points where using one is better than another when over a certain count.  That's mostly why people are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The timer code itself shouldn't have any noticeable performance impact. It's just a few lines of code, after all.

Comment: "X shouldn't have any noticeable performance impact. It's just a few lines of code, after all." lol sounds like the opening to CS horror movie.

Comment: Someone should totally make that.